# Default name for database objects

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, specifications

I'm trying to find out what column name JPA uses when there's no explicit name set.

Example:

```
@Entity
public class TestType {
    private Boolean   active;
    private Character testTypeCode;

    public Boolean getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(Boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    @Id
    public Character getTestTypeCode() {
        return testTypeCode;
    }

    public void setTestTypeCode(Character testTypeCode) {
        this.testTypeCode = testTypeCode;
    }
}
```

What name will be used for the primary key column, which column name will be used for the property "active" and what table name will be used. I'm looking for the specification of what names JPA uses by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the chapter "2.13 Naming of Database Objects" that specifies that ([JPA 2.0 spec](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr317/)).

> This specification requires the following with regard to the
>   interpretation of the names referencing database objects. These names
>   include the names of tables, columns, and other database elements.
>   Such names also include names that result from defaulting (e.g., a
>   table name that is defaulted from an entity name or a column name that
>   is defaulted from a field or property name).

In you example, the table name would be `TestType`, the ID column name `testTypeCode` and the active column would the called the same. Please also note, that in the SQL Standard all column and table names are case insensitive, although there are some counterexamples (e.g MySQL on Unix: the table names are case sensitive).

Comment: As I understand this part of the specification it doesn't state that the names used are the ones of the class or property / field. They're just derived from them. Maybe I'm wrong because I'm not a native speaker. For the primary key however the specification states it very clearly (11.1.18 Id Annotation): `If no Column annotation is specified, the primary key column name is assumed to be the name of
the primary key property or field.`

Comment: We speak here about default names (but which you can overwrite). Table name defaults to entity name. Entity Name is this: `@Entity(name="EntityName")` (which defaults to the simple class name). Now if the expression "defaulting from" makes you thinking (as meaning "derived from"), it shouldn't, because it would cause some portability problems.